# How do you install meteor with choco?

Tags: powershell, meteor, installation, choco

I'm installing Meteor through Choco and so far it only installs version .0.0.4. I believe it should be installing 1.1? Also it installs an empty Meteor folder. How do you get the proper Meteor version to be installed? Where is the choco folder located? I am having trouble understanding how to get choco and meteor to work together.

Comment: the version on the chocolatey site is `Meteor 0.0.5` and was approved on `Saturday, September 19, 2020`. ///// you will find that choco almost always runs behind. ///// i presume you used the instructions from here >>> Install the Latest Version of Meteor | Meteor — https://www.meteor.com/install <<< and they are simply WRONG. [*grin*] you will need to talk to them about getting the correct instructions.

Comment: Thanks for posting your question, you may consider asking it in a more appropriate community dedicated to these specific tools. Take a look at the guidelines for asking questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Anybody know why the folder contents would be empty, or why I am unable to run meteor create _____appname___ ?

Comment: Please use the new [2021 installer](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/npm-packages/meteor-installer/README.md) if you intend to install Meteor on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The Chocolatey website states it is version 0.0.5.
https://chocolatey.org/packages/meteor

When checking the version history (https://chocolatey.org/packages/meteor#versionhistory), Meteor 1.1.1 was never published in the public Chocolatey repository.

The only thing you can do is to send a message to the software authors with the request to update the package. https://chocolatey.org/packages/meteor/ContactOwners.